# How to print structured array and push value in array

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. I am here to learn JQuery fundamentals and serious to know how array works in jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <style>
  div { color:blue; }
  span { color:red; }
</style>
    <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var testArray = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"];
    var new_array=[];
    var vPool="";

    /*i tried but this pushing code dosen't work*/

   //pushing values in new_array
    $("new_array").push({"test1","test2","test3","test4"});

    //fetching the values of new_array 
    $.each(new_array, function(i, val) {
      vPool+=val + "<br />";
    });
    $('#myDiv').html(vPool);--->
    //vPool="";

    /*But i tried this code it work fine */

    //fetching the values of new_array 
    $.each(testArray, function(i, val) {
      vPool+=val + "<br />";
    });
    $('#myDiv').html(vPool); 
    //vPool="";

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to know how to print structured array like we print in PHP:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Are you trying to print in order to debug ? If so use `console.log(arr)` and [look at the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: Array is part of JavaScript. jQuery is a library written in JavaScript.

Comment: i tried console.log but it's doesn't work for me.may i don't aware how to use it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$("")` arround `new_array`. Also you are pushing an object that is defined incorrect. And the `push()` function has nothing to do with jQuery, it is pure JavaScript.

About the *printing* of the whole array you should try `console.log()` in Chrome or Firefox with installed Firebug extension.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var testArray = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"];
    var new_array=[];
    var vPool="";

    /*i tried but this pushing code dosen't work*/

    //pushing values in new_array
    new_array.push("test1","test2","test3","test4");
    console.log(new_array);

    $.each(new_array, function(i, val) {
        vPool+=val + "<br />";
        console.log(val);
    });

});
```

The `push()` function returns the new length of the array.

Comment: :-$(new_array).push({test1,test2,test3,test4}); like this way

Comment: :-i don't know but doesn't work for me sir.i understand but how i know without print anything.....

Comment: console.log(new_array); Try this in chrome.

Comment: i understand but how i know values is pushing into array.i will try console.log(new_array);it's shows [] in firebug.any one tried this code and getting values.iam new to jquery please help me out.

Comment: The `push()` function returns the new length of the array.

Comment: @nic:-it show values in console.log(val);&console.log(new_array) in firebug.you deserve correct mark.great work sir.

Comment: @Nic:-thank you sir please help where i learn JQuery in better way.